# Producing uniform magnetic field along length of a test tube

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have a test tube and I want to apply varying magnetic field along the both the walls (lengthy sides). When one end of the wall is north the other end should be south. i have to observe the solution when the varying magnetic field is applied.
When I tried with strong permanent magnets, as the fields are concentrated near  poles, it is not uniform along the walls. 
Could someone help me directing a way how can I create uniform magnetic field along entire length of test tube?

Answer (score 0):

Use a solenoid coil which surrounds the test tube. make the length of the coil roughly twice the length of the tube. control the strength of the field by varying the DC current through the coil. Monitor the field strength with a hall-effect magnetic field sensor. Have fun.

Comment: Many thanks for the swift reply. I will try that. Any way to still "see" the test tube as I want to watch what is happening inside the tube when field is applied. And another issue noted with solenoid, if solenoid covers length of test tube, isnt it produce fiield lengthwise? I want field between the walls..

Comment: Ooh, I didn't understand that, sorry. What you then need is a horseshoe magnet with a pole face wide enough to cover the "active length" of the tube. Looking sideways through the tube, its contents will be visible, with the N pole of the magnet on one side, and the S pole on the other. Backlight it with a lamp for better visibility.

Comment: Thats fine. I am trying to find electromagnetic equivalent of a horse shoe magnet...so that i can switch poles easily.

Comment: OK. Imagine a horseshoe arrangement, where within the bend of the horseshoe there is an electromagnetic coil. Sending current through the coil turns the horseshoe into a magnet. The cross-section of the horseshoe is rectangular so the width of the end of the horseshoe matches the active length of the test tube. In this case you WILL need a hall-effect sensor because there is a tendency for the horseshoe to retain whichever magnetic polarity it had even after the electricity is turned off, and you will need to account for that.